# SMS messages disappear right after being received

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms

I have LG Optimus one with android 2.3. I get text messages (SMS) and notification appears in the notification bar. But I can't find them (messages) in the "messages" app. They simply disappear!

Comment: Do you have a third-party SMS app like GO SMS Pro, or just the stock Messaging app?

Comment: @geffchang nope. Just stock Messaging app.

Comment: Are you using the stock launcher (like Launcher8), or a 3rd-party launcher?

Comment: This may be a Gingerbread bug. Lots of people have been reporting disappearing SMS. Have you ever tried updating your firmware via Software Update?

Comment: @geffchang solved. I had to set up date. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by set up date? Set the date and time of the phone? If so, please post that as an Answer, and mark it as Answer when you are able to.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have set up date right! I have just observed that the date was set to 01.01.1980 and changed it to the current date and everything started working right.